# Azure pipeline docker fails copy with multiple projects

Tags: azure-devops, dockerfile

Copying of Data.csproj to Data/ is failing when building my app in azure devops. Though, the first copy command, Api.csproj to Api/ is working fine. Do note that I did not specify the buildContext on my azure-pipeline.yml file. But, when I did add the buildContext, **buildContext: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'**, it failed even on the first copy.

Any inputs or suggestion on how to fix this one? I tried searching and adding the buildcontext or adding the folder on the csproj doesn't seem to work. For example, COPY ["/Data/Data.csproj", "Data/"]

This is my folder structure (my azure-pipeline.yml file is outside the App folder):

```
App
- Api/
  - Api.csproj
  - Dockerfile
- Data/
  - Data.csproj
- Domain/
  - Domain.csproj
- App.sln
```

My dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["Api.csproj", "Api/"]
COPY ["Data.csproj", "Data/"]
COPY ["Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]
```

parts of my azure-pipeline.yml

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: 'App'
        dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'               
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Here's the error:

```
Step 6/28 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> Running in 266a78d293ee
Removing intermediate container 266a78d293ee
 ---> 2d899fafdf05
Step 7/28 : COPY ["Api.csproj", "Api/"]
 ---> 92c8c1450c3c
Step 8/28 : COPY ["Data.csproj", "Data/"]
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder764823890/Data.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder764823890/Data.csproj: no such file or directory
##[error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after trying so many times, I was able to fix this by changing the dockerfile and azure-pipelines.yml.

I think what fixed the issue is to specifically set the buildContext to 'App/' instead of the variable '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)' that I'm not sure what's the exact value.

I'll just post the part that I made changes to.

Dockerfile

```
COPY ["Api/Api.csproj", "Api/"]
COPY ["Data/Data.csproj", "Data/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
```

azure-pipelines.yml

```
inputs:
  command: buildAndPush
  repository: $(imageRepository)
  dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)        
  buildContext: 'App/'
```